# Is it possible and reasonable to use a i386 rpm driver on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, driver, printing, cups

I have a Dell Color Laser 1320c (or Fuji Xerox C525 A; their drivers seem to be compatible) and want to use it in a CUPS server on a Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately, I can only find a i386 driver as a rpm file. I found out that I can convert that rpm file to a deb file using a tool called alien. Also, I can use a feature called Multiarch to use i368 software on that RPi.

So, what's the best approach in a situation like this?

Honestly, I'm just not sure if I'm on the right track or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You can't use Intel x86 software on the ARM based Pi.

Comment: That's what I was thinking and then I found [this](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading). Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: i386 is Intel 32 bit, amd64 is Intel clone 64 bit.  The amd64 chip is probably a superset of the i386 chip and can run the same code.  There is no relationship between ARM chips and Intel chips.

Comment: Can you get the rpm equivalent of the deb-src package and recompile the source code.  Unfortunately for drivers it can be very hit or miss as to whether they could be ported to different architecture - for instance the RPi does not have the "parport" hardware so a driver that wants to talk to THAT is not going to fly, on the other hand if it only wants to talk to the usb subsystem and it does so through a public API to the "standard" linux usb kernel implementation then it may be possible to port a driver's source code.  Also, what happens if you ask CUPS to try and find the printer as it is?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Pi has an ARM based CPU. It's not compatible with x86.

Even if it were compatible you still might have to do some massaging to get those rpm drivers installed in the correct place, among other things. But that's moot.

I know nothing about running CUPS on the Pi, perhaps there is a generic PostScript driver? Or a jetdirect driver if your printer supports it?